# how to label a sentiment using Stanford NLP?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to find sentiment of tweets using Stanford NLP package. Here is the example tweet

**@SouthwestAir Fastest response all day. Hour on the phone: never got off hold. Hour in line: never got to the Flight Booking Problems desk.**

Here Stanford NLP labels sentiment based on sentence. So, this tweet has three sentences with full-stops. Hence NLP gives me three different sentiment lables for each sentence of tweet. Now how can I label entire tweet as positive , negative or neutral ?

```
Neutral    @SouthwestAir Fastest response all day.
Negative    Hour on the phone: never got off hold.
Negative    Hour in line: never got to the Flight Booking Problems desk.
```

Comment: Which library are you using? Aren't there any arguments to remove punctuation and stopwords, tokenize the words, or directly ask for one label per block?

Comment: See this and previous years for methods, tools, etc: http://alt.qcri.org/semeval2016/task4/

Answer (score 0):

The sentiment software we release produces sentiment judgments per sentence.  You will have to come up with a heuristic to turn that into document level sentiment.  For each tweet you might look at the set of sentence level judgments {neutral, negative, negative} and just map that to a final judgment.  One way might be to just take the judgment with highest count.  Tweets are going to be short, so usually you're probably looking at most at 3 sentiments to collapse into one per tweet.